# How can I handle a HashMap with (potentially) multiple types in its values being passed to a function?

Tags: rust

I need to pass a `HashMap` to a function, but this `HashMap` could theoretically have both integers and strings as values. How do I form the type signature of the function in question for this? I'm new to Rust, and after trying `fn do_thing(params: &HashMap<String, _>)` and meeting with failure, I ran out of ideas.

```
fn do_thing(params: &HashMap<String, _>) {
    // Irrelevant - regardless, the compiler fails because I cannot use the type placeholder in a function's type sig.
}

fn main() {
    let params = HashMap::new();
    params.insert(field, value); // field will always be a string, value could be a string or an integer
    do_thing(&params)
}
```

---

This is *not* a duplicate of the suggested question - constructing a `HashMap` does not require type declarations, whereas this concerns the `HashMap` being a function's parameter, which does.

Comment: Why do not you use an `enum`?

Comment: @Boiethios Would enums work if I couldn't be sure of the keys ahead of time?

Comment: I do not understand your question

Comment: The HashMap in my code is constructed without any guarantee of what the keys might be. AFAIK, an enum wouldn't work in this scenario.

Comment: Can you add a [mcve].

Comment: @rjcoupe How do you construct the `HashMap`? Would be helpful included in the question.

Comment: What do you mean by "without any guarantee of what the keys might be"? Will they all be the same type?

Comment: Apologies - the _values_ could potentially be different types. The keys will always be strings.

Comment: Then use an enum for the values.

Comment: The solution is the same - use an enum. Whether the type is implicit (when constructed it can be inferred) or explicit is orthogonal. Putting multiple types where one type is required will use an enum, and then you have to put that type in signatures or in structs, etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your value can be int or string, use an `enum` as follow:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

enum Value {
    Int(i32),
    String(String),
}

fn do_thing(params: &HashMap<String, Value>) {
    // each value of params can be Int or String. Check it with a match.
}
```

Check with a match if `Value` is `Int` or `String`:

```
match val {
    Value::Int(i)    => //do something with i
    Value::String(s) => //do something with s
}
```